# Getting GDAL to work in Python (libjpeg.so.8: cannot open shared object file)

Tags: linux, python-2.7, anaconda, gdal, libjpeg

I have been trying to get GDAL to work from Python (Anaconda) for quite a while, but I am not able to figure it out. Would be great if someone can help me out.

First I tried to install gdal from conda. This seemed like it worked.

```
solo@debian:/etc/opt$ conda install gdal
Fetching package metadata .........
Solving package specifications: .
# All requested packages already installed.
# packages in environment at /home/solo/anaconda2:
gdal  2.1.0 py27_0
```

But when I try to import gdal from Anaconda-Python, I get this error:

```
Python 2.7.13 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Dec 20 2016, 23:09:15) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://anaconda.org
>>> import gdal
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named gdal
>>>
```

But I followed the standard approach to install gdal into my (sudo) user default Python (the one that is loaded when I do "sudo Python") and it seems to work fine. The version of Python in my sudo user is:

```
solo@debian:/etc/opt$ sudo python
Python 2.7.9 (default, Jun 29 2016, 13:08:31) 
[GCC 4.9.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import gdal
>>>
```

When I run gdalinfo from the command line, with and without sudo, I get different results too:

```
solo@debian:/etc/opt$ sudo gdalinfo
Usage: gdalinfo [--help-general] [-mm] [-stats] [-hist] [-nogcp] [-nomd]
                [-norat] [-noct] [-nofl] [-checksum] [-proj4] [-mdd domain]*
                [-sd subdataset] datasetname

FAILURE: No datasource specified.
solo@debian:/etc/opt$ gdalinfo
gdalinfo: error while loading shared libraries: libjpeg.so.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

How can I get gdal to work from Python without sudo? I tried several Stackoverflow solutions to fix libjpeg.so.8, but have not managed to sort this out.